# Why does NLog.dll contain a JetBrains.Annotations namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, nlog

I've been ported over some of my code to use NLog, which is great so far.  However, I ran into a compiler error on the following code:

```
[UsedImplicitly(ImplicitUseTargetFlags.Members)]
private class SomeClass
```

The error is:

> Error 96  The type 'JetBrains.Annotations.UsedImplicitlyAttribute'
>   exists in both
>   'c:\Code\packages\Twia.ReSharper.1.1.0\lib\net40\JetBrains.Annotations.dll'
>   and 'c:\Code\packages\NLog.3.0.0.0\lib\net45\NLog.dll'

Sure enough, NLog.dll contains a JetBrains.Annotations.UsedImplicitlyAttribute class:

[image]

I, of course, don't have control over the source code for either one of these.  Why in the world does NLog have its own *copy* of this class?  Did they ILMerge the JetBrains code into the assembly or something?  Is the implementation the same?  Am I safe to now *remove* the reference to `JetBrains.Annotations.dll` and have everything work the same?  Is there a work around to reference both assemblies without the compiler errors?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is/was a [known issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/292).

The good news it was [fixed](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/commit/addc17e96ee3fec661166b865eb29164df4aac11), just eight hours ago.  The bad news is that now I'll have to wait for the next version of NLog, since I don't want to build from source.

**Update:**

I found a temporary fix while I wait until the next release.  In Visual Studio, find the *NLog* reference in the project:

[image]

Right click, select *Properties*.  Then, change the *Aliases* value from *Global* to something else, such as *NLog*:

[image]

This will make the conflict go away.  However, then when you want to reference *anything* from that assembly, you have to fully qualify it by:

1. Adding `extern alias NLog;` to the *very top* of your .cs file (before any `using` keywords) and...
2. Prefixing the namespace with `NLog::`, for example:

`public class Logger : NLog::NLog.LogReceiverService.ILogReceiverServer`

Still wondering what the NLog guys were thinking putting a third party namespace into their assembly and making it public.